# How to access a variable defined in service class from a component in Angular 9?

Tags: angular, mean-stack, mern, web-frontend

I am making a chat application wherein the service class after login I am setting a local variable as true. But when I am trying to access that variable from another component it gives me the initial value which is false. So how to go about it ?

**auth.service.ts**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  
  url:string = 'http://localhost:3000/api/'
  
  public isAuth: boolean = false

  login(user:User){
    const api = this.url + 'signin'
    return this.http.post<any>(api,user,httpOptions).subscribe(response => {
      if(response.token){
 
        localStorage.setItem('token',response.token)
        isAuth = true
        this.router.navigate(['chat'])
      }
      
    })
  }  

}
```

**chatroom.component.ts**

```
import {AuthService} from '../services/auth.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-chatroom',
  templateUrl: './chatroom.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chatroom.component.css']
})
export class ChatroomComponent implements OnInit,AfterViewInit{

 constructor(private auth:AuthService) { }
   
 ngOnInit(): void {

     console.log(this.auth.isAuth) //is showing me false despite logging in and setting it to true
  }

}
```

Comment: `this.auth.isAuth` is assigned asynchronously. It isn't assigned `true` yet when you're accessing it from the other component.

Answer (score 0):

**after setting value to local storage channge**

```
isAuth = true
```

to

```
this.isAuth = true
```